# Webform for each item in a view

Tags: views, webforms

I have a view of events and I want each event to have a "Register" button that brings up a webform form for the event. Obviously the filled out form should be saved so that I can tell who signed up for which event. I'm pretty new to Drupal so I'm not sure what the best approach is to associate each event with a webform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you have to attach the webform to the content type(under webform settings) and then you can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_default_fields to add fields to the web form.
cheers

Comment: If you don't want to use a webform,you may use signup module or similar modules(registration etc)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to attach the webforms to the content type and how to use webforms default fields?

Comment: First enable webform,then visit the content type you wish to attache the webform e.g. admin/structure/types/manage/article ,visit webfrom tab and enable the webform functionality.Then install the webform default fields.After that,visit a node of the content type you attached the webform,select the webform tab and add the fields